# What is "dein nicht achten" in Goethe's Prometheus?

Tags: genitive, poetry

*Dein* seems to be the genitive old-fashioned form of the [second person personal pronoun in singular](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/du), thus the old-fashioned form of *deiner*.
The end of Goethe's [*Prometheus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_(Goethe)) is

> Und **dein** nicht zu achten,
>   Wie ich!

He is referring to Zeus. The transformation to modern German, only for purpose of comprehension, would be in two steps, I guess: First, take the old *dein* to *deiner*; secondly, transform *deiner* to the usual accusative form *dich*.

My question is, whether the second transformation is possible without loosing information (of course, style is lost). Whether *Dich nicht zu achten* says the same, or this *dein* rather means "to scorn every possible aspect of you". Or whether the only possible transformation to modern German would stop at the first step (*deiner nicht zu achten*)?

Answer (score 7):

Your analysis is correct. In modern German you would say "und dich nicht zu achten". I do not think there is any loss of information, though there is possibly a loss of poetic gravitas.

Answer (score -2):

Is Goethe talking about Zeus? Is he talking about God in general? Is he talking about the church? **What is his message?**

Prometheus was created in the ["Sturm und Drang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm_und_Drang) period. Which according to the Wikipedia article is all about emotional liberation.

The verses

> "Zu leiden, zu weinen, Zu genießen und zu freuen sich,"

underlines this sentiment.

Since criticizing the catholic church, society or christian god directly probably was not a good idea Goethe used Zeus as a stand in.

In this perspective dein stands for the **essence** or dase **Wesen** of the thing or things that needs to be ignored in order to be emotionally free.

I'd even say you could easily replace:

> **Dein nicht zu achten**

with:

> **Dein Wesen nicht zu achten.**

or:

> **Deinen Einfluss zu ignorieren.**

Comment: This answer is wrong. As correctly stated in the question "dein" is here the older form of the genitive of the pronoun (modern German: "deiner"). If the poet meant "dein Hab und Gut" he would have written "Deines".